# Like button per-item, max number of "manage" pages, overkill?

Tags: php, facebook, e-commerce, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have coded an e-commerce website to include a dynamic like button on each item page. In doing this each time a Facebook User clicks the like button, a new page is created under the Admin accounts "Manage Pages" list. Firstly is there a limit to the number of pages one can manage? It almost seems like it would be a huge headache to manage all of those pages for an apparent infinite amount of items.

If that is a poorly chosen way to go about things, how is it normally done? Do sites merely have the "share this" button which does not "like" anything but just posts it to the users wall?

I will take any suggestions.

Thank you.

** Edit **
It appears I could have been more clear. The use does not see any sort of new page or anything when they click the like. However, Facebook internally creates a new "Manage" page for each different like button which is clicked for internal management. Therefore if someone were to "Like" all of the items in the site, I would have 500 "pages" to manage in Facebook.

Apparently the "Share" is deprecated and they want everyone to do the like going forward so it seems like there shouldn't be a limit -- it just seems that it would be a logistical nightmare.

Comment: Why exactly is a new page created when the user likes an already existing item page? Wouldn't the user "like" the page s/he is already in?

Comment: Perhaps it was phrased incorrectly, I am not creating a new page, I am talking about Facebook's management of "Liked" pages.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently researched this quite a bit for www.bargain.com. It seems that simply sharing things is the most efficient and rewarding for investment of resources. Load times can be hit pretty hard (If you care about milliseconds) when like buttons are loaded several times per page, for example. If there was very heavy traffic and load times were being slowed slightly by heaps of buttons, it may actually be an issue in the cae of bargain.com. I tried to streamline that as well as possible but it ends up being pretty heavy.

Ultimately, I just hate these buttons. Share, like, plus, whatever. Haha.

Also, would a user really expect a new page to be created upon clicking like? I think they'd expect to click like and just move on. Creating an entire page seems excessive.

Comment: Facebook is the one who creates the page when it's clicked not I. It's as if they create an internal admin page for each like button clicked.

Comment: @promiseofcake I understand that. I just mean to say that the user probably wouldn't have the intention of spurring the creation of a page upon clicking a like button. For all intents and purposes, it seems superflous to have the page as a result of such a mundane action.

Comment: But I have no control over this. That is where the question is coming from. The buyer does not see anything new such as a page, etc. But when the Facebook admin logs in, they have a page created, under the Manage Pages heading, for every liked item.